I filed my taxes not knowing I was being claimed as a dependent meaning that the Head of Household will have more deducted than before
I filed my own taxes unaware that I could be and apparently was being claimed as a dependent, so it's been brought to my attention that the Head of Household could have a higher standard deduction than previously because I filed as a non-dependent. Is there any way I can amend my return to, in a manner of speaking, undo any additional deductions I may have inadvertently added?

File an amended return.

Of course you should check that you do indeed meet the rules to be a dependent, and evaluate the overall impact it may have on your taxes.

I'm 20, work part time, but I'm not enrolled in any school. I don't pay any of the household expenses at the moment either, so could I still qualify?

@BenConnor: Go through this document and compare it to your circumstances.

In order to amend a mistake on your tax return you file... an amended tax return. Here's the IRS page on amending returns, with links to all the related information and instructions you might need.
